# How to run a symlink pointing to an executable in terminal (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link, environment-variables

I installed NodeJs on an Ubuntu machine, and the package have been installed as `nodejs`. Now, to run it as `node`, I created a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

This will work if I call the symlink directly, but it don't allow me to simply call `node` to start the program.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Some more investigation: Does nodejs work when running it as "nodejs" and what exactly is the error message you get when trying to run it as "node"? Another thing: You could take a look at nvm (Node Version Manager), it's good if you need a special version of node that  is not provided by the package manager.

Comment: @FSMaxB Running `nodejs` [works as expected](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint). But that's not enough as every other program rely on `node` being available as a command globally. Running `node` don't do anything - no error message.

Comment: Maybe an alias in /etc/profile can help, but this won't work if node is run by the exec systemcall. What software are you using that depend on node?

Comment: @FSMaxB I tried aliasing too, that was working in the command line, but wasn't working for executable declaring `#!/usr/bin/env node`. I have a lot of program running on node like Mocha unit test, Yeoman, Grunt, that I'd like to get running on Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't really know much more to do other than trying a fresh install, but there's one idea that came to me right now: Not using a symlink but writing a bash script "/usr/bin/node" with "#!/bin/sh" and "/usr/bin/nodejs ......." inside (and somehow passing the parameters passed to the script on to nodejs, I'm not that good at bash programming)

Comment: Ok, I don't know why, but my node symlink had to be in `/usr/sbin/node` (and not in the `bin` folder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about symlinking executables in general, this should automatically work out of the box. Make sure /usr/bin/nodejs is executable by everybody, and restart the terminal. In any case, calling `node` directly from anywhere in a terminal should work normally.

If `node` appears to execute properly but NodeJs itself does not like being called as `node` instead of `nodejs`, that's a different problem.

Comment: Hey, I just realized that typing the full path of the symlink works (e.g.: `/usr/bin/node`). But if I only type `node` it doesn't - do I have to set something in my PATH or in my terminal?

Comment: @SimonBoudrias make sure your PATH variable contains "/usr/bin" you can check that by typing "env | grep PATH". It is however, very improbable that "/usr/bin" is not in your PATH variable, as your system  shouldn't work properly  if this was the case.

Comment: @FSMaxB It is there... (if it helps, I'm running Ubuntu in a virtual machine via virtual box)

Answer (score 2):

There is a program "node" in Ubuntu, that has nothing to do with Node.js. Just uninstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove node
```

(You would find the answer, if you tried `whereis node`.)